# Yolo: PyTorch vs. Darknet

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I have recently found Yolo implementations in PyTorch (e.g. https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3). What I would like to know if this is really the same (in terms of model accuracy, speed and so on) like the one with Darknet backbone?

I am asking because it is waaaaaay easier with PyTorch (as I am struggling with installing Darknet on windows).

Comment: For experimentation, and training, Python implementations are perfect, and ultralytics provides mAP comparisons with original. Inference speed can never match an optimised C++ implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step to install darknet framework on window10.
I recommend to clone darknet from AlexeyAB repository since it works great on windows10 and a lot of community support.(https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet).
And now it has a python wrapper so you could implement it on python.

1. Clone darknet repositoriey.
2. install vcpkg.(https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)
3. Install visual studio 2017.
4. Install CUDA and CUDNN.
5. Add CUDNN into system environment. Variable name = 'CUDNN' , variable value =
   'installed path'.
6. Add 'CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR' into system environment. Variable name = 'CUDNN',
   variable value = 'installed path\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2.
7. build with powershell command '.\build.ps1' in darknet directory.

Answer (score 0):

The python implementations will never be as fast as the C/C++ version of Darknet.  Not sure which repo you were trying to install on Windows.  Note the popular AlexeyAB version has been abandoned for several years.  The new Darknet/YOLO repo with the new Windows installation method can be found here:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

Answer (score -1):

YOLO (You Only Look Once) is a one shot detector method to detect object in a certain image. It can work with Darknet, Pytorch, Tensorflow, Keras etc. frameworks. YOLO and darknet complements together pretty well as it has a robust support for CUDA & CUDNN. Use whichever framework you want !!